# BigQuery: generate and explode array with exceptions based on another array

Tags: sql, arrays, exception, google-bigquery, sequence

I have a table with these arrays:

| ids | ids_positions | ids_position_exceptions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5] | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] | [2, 3] |
| [A1, A2, A3, A4] | [0, 1, 2, 3] | [0] |

**ids** and **ids_positions** will always have the same length. Basically **ids_positions** contains the index of each element of **ids**

**ids_positions** will always be ascending ordered, from 0 to a number n.

**ids_position_exceptions** contains some numbers from **ids_positions** that should be excluded in the final result (sometimes this array could be null, so no exclusions should be done)

I need this:

| id | positions |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 0 |
| A2 | 1 |
| A3 | 4 |
| A4 | 5 |
| A5 | 6 |
| A1 | 1 |
| A2 | 2 |
| A3 | 3 |
| A4 | 4 |

I have to explode by row the array_positions without the elements in array_exceptions and add the new values to continue the sequence.

For example, in the first row, I have 5 ids. There are two exceptions so I have to remove them and add the same numbers of elements at the end. I removed 2 and 3, and add 5 and 6.

I was thinking in something like: generate an array from 0 to the length of **ids_positions** + **ids_position_exceptions** with an except if one element of the sequence generated is in array_exception. Then explode this new array into a column.

Idk if BigQuery have an ARRAY_EXCEPT function like SparkSQL but I think it's what I need for this case.

It's a big data problem, so the solution must be cost-effective

Thank you!

Comment: it is not appreciated here on SO, when you change your question after you've got already answers! two answers!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it. When I saw your answer I realize that the simplification that I made here to explain my problem was wrong.

Comment: I agreed with @Mikhail's opinion.  It made inital answers not relavant to your question. Anyway I've updated my answer, so kindly check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select id, position from your_table t, t.array_positions position
except distinct
select id, exception from your_table t, t.array_exceptions exception
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Below is answer on updated question

```
select id, position from (
  select ids, array(
      (select * from t.ids_positions except distinct select * from t.ids_position_exceptions)
      union all
      select array_length(ids_positions) + i - 1 
      from unnest(generate_array(1, array_length(ids_position_exceptions))) i
    ) new_positions
  from your_table t
), unnest(ids) id with offset
join unnest(new_positions) position with offset
using(offset)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: I just edited the question because I explained my issue very bad, I'm sorry. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Using a **set** operation looks excellent and below is an another possible option without a **set** operation.

```sql
SELECT id, p AS positions
  FROM sample, UNNEST(array_positions) p
 WHERE p NOT IN UNNEST(array_exceptions)
```

output:

[image]

below query is for your updated question :

```sql
SELECT id, position
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ARRAY_LENGTH(array_exceptions) AS len_ex,
           (SELECT AS STRUCT MAX(p) maxpos, ARRAY_AGG(p) pos 
              FROM UNNEST(array_positions) p 
             WHERE p NOT IN UNNEST(array_exceptions)) AS ex
      FROM sample
  ),
UNNEST(ids) id WITH OFFSET JOIN 
UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT(
         ex.pos, 
         GENERATE_ARRAY(ex.maxpos + 1, ex.maxpos + len_ex)
      )) position WITH OFFSET USING (offset)
;
```

[image]

Comment: I just edited the question because I explained my issue very bad, I'm sorry. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the size of your data but I would take [UDF approach](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) on bigquery as this sounds easy to solve programmatically using simple array operations, use the function & unnest the values using offset as mentioned in the above solution.

Query:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  getNewIdPositions(ids ARRAY<STRING>,
    id_positions ARRAY<INT64>,
    id_position_exceptions ARRAY<INT64>)
  RETURNS ARRAY<INT64>
  LANGUAGE js AS r"""
  var filteredArray = id_positions.filter(function (x) {
  return id_position_exceptions.indexOf(x) < 0;
  });
  for(let i = 0; i < id_position_exceptions.length; i++) {
    filteredArray.push(Number(filteredArray[filteredArray.length - 1]) + 1)
  }
  return filteredArray;
""";
WITH
  sample_data AS (
  SELECT
    ['A1',
    'A2',
    'A3',
    'A4',
    'A5'] AS ids,
    [0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4] AS id_positions,
    [2,
    3] AS id_position_exceptions
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ['A1',
    'A2',
    'A3',
    'A4'] AS ids,
    [0,
    1,
    2,
    3] AS id_positions,
    [0] AS id_positions_exceptions )
SELECT
  flat_ids,
  flat_pos
FROM (
  SELECT
    ids,
    getNewIdPositions(ids,
      id_positions,
      sample_data.id_position_exceptions) AS new_id_positions
  FROM
    sample_data )a,
  UNNEST(ids) flat_ids
WITH
OFFSET
JOIN
  UNNEST(a.new_id_positions) flat_pos
WITH
OFFSET
USING
  (
  OFFSET
    )
```

Result:

[image]